# PHP fopen and fread proper format

Tags: fopen, lines, fread

So i'm trying to get a fopen and fread statement to display logs and each entry is formatted in a new line, how can I get my code to go in the same format as the .txt,

.txt :

```
[2014/1/19 - 22:49:37] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 expire time to 60
[2014/1/19 - 22:49:43] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 1 (Enabled)
[2014/1/19 - 22:49:51] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to Free House
[2014/1/19 - 22:49:59] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 5000000
[2014/1/19 - 22:50:31] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 0 (disabled)
[2014/1/19 - 22:50:37] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to none
[2014/1/19 - 22:50:45] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to (none)
[2014/1/19 - 22:50:50] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 0
[2014/1/20 - 11:40:09] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to Testing House
[2014/1/20 - 11:40:14] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 expire time to 1
[2014/1/20 - 11:40:18] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 1
[2014/1/20 - 11:40:21] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 1 (Enabled)
```

PHP Return:

```
[2014/1/19 - 22:49:37] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 expire time to 60 [2014/1/19 - 22:49:43] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 1 (Enabled) [2014/1/19 - 22:49:51] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to Free House [2014/1/19 - 22:49:59] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 5000000 [2014/1/19 - 22:50:31] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 0 (disabled) [2014/1/19 - 22:50:37] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to none [2014/1/19 - 22:50:45] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to (none) [2014/1/19 - 22:50:50] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 0 [2014/1/20 - 11:40:09] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 item description to Testing House [2014/1/20 - 11:40:14] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 expire time to 1 [2014/1/20 - 11:40:18] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 starting bid to 1 [2014/1/20 - 11:40:21] Josh (IP:174.101.171.132) has edited auction 0 enabled to 1 (Enabled)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited you post twice, with the first edit I cleaned up the mess in the lower part, until I realized that this is your actual problem. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file');
```

gives you an array where every element is a line of the file.

http://php.net/file

Answer (score 0):

use fgets

fgets reads one line of text from the file. If you are outputting it to an HTML stream, the output one line at a time and add `<BR>` after each line.  Or, just use `<pre></pre>` tags and output the entire file as is.